# Find quaternion rotation

Tags: quaternions

Given units quaternions $p$ and $q$, how do you find the quaternion $r$ such as:

$$
rpr^{-1} = q
$$

In other terms, how to find the rotation transforming $p$ to $q$?

Comment: Get an intuitive understanding of quaternions here: https://eater.net/quaternions/

Answer (score 0):

The rotation applies on *vectors* of $\mathbb{R}^3$, not on quaternions.